# Calculate volume using double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, riemann-integration

I'm trying to calculate the following integral:

$$I=\iint_{D}(x-\frac{7}{3})y \; dxdy,$$
where $D$ is the area limited by the curves $\frac{7}{3}-2y-x=0$ and $x=\frac{1}{3}y^{2}$.

I'll insert a picture of my solution. I would love to hear if you can find somewhere where I've done something crucially wrong. I just can't get the right answer at the moment. I'm not expecting you to control all the constants and do the whole calculation since it's very time consuming.

Thanks!

[image: My solution]

Comment: It is advisable to use mathjax to type in your work. Also, you may want to use change of variables to simplify your work.

Comment: @MathLover yeah that's true. I'm not very experienced with variable subs in double integrals yet. What would be a preferable substitution here?

Comment: I just edited my answer. Please see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral set up is correct but there is a mistake in your work.

$\displaystyle \small I = \int_{-7}^1 y \left[\int_{y^2/3}^{(7/3 - 2y)} \left (x - \frac 73 \right) dx \right]  dy = \int_{-7}^1 y \left[\frac {x^2}2 - \frac {7x}3\right]_{y^2/3}^{7/3-2y}  dy$

$\small \displaystyle = \int_{-7}^1 y \left(\frac 12 \left(\color{blue}{\frac {49}9} - \frac {28y}{3} + 4y^2\right) - \frac73 \left(\frac73-2y\right) - \frac{y^4}{18} + \frac{7y^2}{9} \right)  dy$

See the part highlighted in blue. You instead have $ \displaystyle \frac{21}{9}$. Rest of the work is correct and you get an answer of $-512$ after fixing the mistake.

---

Change of variables can simplify the work.

$u = x - \frac 73, v = y^2$ does simplify the  integrand as the Jacobian of transformation is $\frac{1}{|y|}$ but you need to be careful about the sign.

Even $X = x - \frac{7}{3}$ simplifies the work to an extent. The equations of the curves are then,

$2y + X = 0, y^2 = 3X + 7$

The integral becomes,

$ \small \displaystyle I = \int_{-7}^1 y \left[\int_{(y^2-7)/3}^{-2y} X ~ dX \right]  dy$

$ \displaystyle \small = \frac 1 {18} \int_{-7}^1 (50 y^3 - y^5 - 49y) ~dy$